# How to use a condition inside a while loop?

Tags: python

I have a line of codes to check if the entered value exsist in the database
and will continue to loop but inside the while loop it also print the else statement which it shouldn't

```
cottageNotAvailable = False
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM reserved")
occupide = 0
name = input("Enter Name: ")
cottage_row = int(input("Select Cottage Row: "))
while cottage_row < 1 or cottage_row > 2:
cottage_row = int(input("Select Cottage Row: "))
cottage = int(input("Select Cottage: "))

##ROW 1 Cottages
if cottage_row == 1:
   subtotals = 1000
   ##Check Cottage if available
   users = mycursor.fetchall()
   for allUser in users:
       if str(cottage) in str(allUser[3]):
           cottageNotAvailable = True

   while cottage < 1 or cottage > 5 or cottageNotAvailable:
                    print("======Cottage is not available=======")
                    cottage = int(input("Select Cottage: "))
                    for allUser2 in users:
                        if(str(cottage) in str(allUser2[3])):
                            print("1")
                        else:
                            print('2')
```

1. When Value exsist it print 1 and 2

Output:
1
2

2. When Value does not exsist it just print. Which works fine
   2
   inside the while loop if the value exsist the else shouldn't also trigger

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code, data, logs, input/output, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, paste it into your question as a formatted code block. Thanks!

Comment: `cottageNotAvailable == True` is redundant, just use `...or cottageNotAvailable`.

Comment: Also, you should `print(cottage, allUser2[3])` to make sure they are exactly what you think they are. Your logic might be right, but using `in` for comparing numbers sounds weird to me... but maybe its what you need.

Comment: I see it prints the second value row in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of `cottage` and `users`? What does `allUser2[3]` value return ? Based on the condition check the value of `str(cottage) in str(allUser2[3])`

Comment: applogies. Cottage is the input number more like of seats. users is a variable to feach the reserved database and allUser[3] is the specific row return

Comment: Once check the values of `cottage and str(allUser2[3])` in the loop. It must be true for first and being printed 1 and false for the second and being printed 2

Comment: I see it prints the second value row in the database: